# Ambari error during installation yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari, bigdata

i'm trying to install IBM Open Platform 4.1 on Linux RedHat6; i created local repository for IOP and IOP-UTILS, because of proxy that block connection to ibm.

I installed ambari correctly but during installation of all packages i get this error:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofyZo.png)

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install 'hadoop_4_1_*-yarn'' returned 1.

Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Try executing this command (/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install 'hadoop_4_1_*-yarn') manually. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, i have the same error # /usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install 'hadoop_4_1_*-yarn'
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Do you see the yarn package in your local repository? This message is usually seen when the package is missing.

Comment: OK this is the problem, with command yum list, in avaiable package i see all packages of IOP and IOP-UTILS except Hadoop packages (included yarn), how can i add them in yum repo?

Comment: Problem fixed, i was using the wrong OS packages